# How to include headers into my library without exposing them to users?

Tags: c++, include, static-libraries, header-files, libraries

Recently I've been making a basic GUI that I plan on turning into a static library for use in the future.

To make it, I used the Win32 API, OpenGL and various other functions from the C++ standard library.

I was just wondering, is there anyway I can restrict the user from accessing these functions?

For example, when I use some 3rd party library, I am unable to access any of the functions from the C++ standard library without including their respective headers myself, even though I'm sure they are used in said library.

So is there any way to disallow the user to use specific functions provided in specific headers?

Comment: Um, if you don't want to allow a function to be used, don't put it in your header.

Comment: Don't include those headers in your public interface (headers). Provide forward declarations for all private types (if they are part of the interface).

Comment: export only what you need... in case of classes you can export whole class but only public will be accessible from the outside ...You can also use namespace ...